# Should I post questions about my autistic child here or on SE Health?

Tags: discussion

My son is autistic, very mild condition tho. I have many questions about his condition and how should I act as a parent. 
Should I post them here? or just because they are about autism they need to get posted at SE health?

Comment: Please read https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic before posting to Health.SE, though. Questions about general medical topic you are welcome, but requests for personal medical advice are off-topic and will be closed. It sounds like you are looking for the former, but just making sure.

Answer (score 5):

I have a feeling this will depend on the question. Some questions will be appropriate here as they are focused on parenting, some may be better on health as they actually depend on health, and some may be too narrow or possibly opinion based, or possibly duplicates as many parenting techniques will be the same for autistic kids as those who don't suffer from autism.

I'd suggest reviewing our [about] and [ask] pages and then posting them if they feel right here in that context.

Worst scenario they may be migrated or closed, but those aren't the end of the world.

Comment: Agree it depends on the question. If you need to know how to _respond to_ a behavior or symptom, that's Parenting; how to _treat_ a symptom, that's Health. There's some overlap that can probably be resolved by careful phrasing.